# VSTO: Managed Folder folderadd event

Tags: vsto

I want to fire the FolderAdd event in Outlook whenever someone drag and drop (add) a folder into Outook Folders (collection)

The FolderAdd event triggered if the folders collection is from Inbox but if I switch it to Managed Folders and it's sub folder's collection. Let's say Managed Folders -> FolderFoo. The FolderAdd event will not fire whenever I drag and drop folder into FolderFoo.

Why Managed Folder's sub folder's folder collection doesn't trigger FolderAdd event but Inbox will?

What I'm trying to do is monitoring a sub folder in Managed Folders and check how big it get whenever someone drop a folder into the Managed Folder's FolderFoo.

Comment: I find the answers to this. You have to set the sub folder to the monitoring folder in order to trigger folderadd event. see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/92ca3f73-17db-4825-b3d5-71454e261eda)